# Android BottomNavigationMenu with dynamic FloatingActionButton placement

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

Is there any possibility to create a BottomNavigationMenu such as CircleBar for iOS? (Link: https://github.com/softhausHQ/CircleBar)

I've been struggling around for several hours to find a solution, but always ended up with buggy custom views.

At best I would like to implement the view using Jetpack Compose.